# solidity code compilation error?

Tags: solidity, remix, truffle-contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        uint8 vote;
        // address delegate;
    }

    //modifer
    modifier onlyOwner () {
      require(msg.sender == chairperson);
      _;
    }

    /* struct Proposal {
        uint voteCount; // could add other data about proposal
    } */
    address public chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
    uint[4] public proposals;

    // Create a new ballot with 4 different proposals.
    function Ballot() public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 2;
    }

    /// Give $(toVoter) the right to vote on this ballot.
    /// May only be called by $(chairperson).
    function register(address toVoter) public onlyOwner{
        if(voters[toVoter].weight != 0) revert();
        voters[toVoter].weight = 1;
        voters[toVoter].voted = false;
    }

    /// Give a single vote to proposal $(toProposal).
    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= 4 || sender.weight == 0) revert();
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal] += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public view returns (uint8 _winningProposal) {
        uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint8 prop = 0; prop < 4; prop++)
            if (proposals[prop] > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[prop];
                _winningProposal = prop;
            }
    }

    function getCount() public view returns (uint[8]) {
        return proposals;
    }
}
```

> truffle compile

```
Compiling ./contracts/Ballot.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:26:5: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    function Ballot() public {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Ballot {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Migrations {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).



/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:26:5: SyntaxError: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.
    function Ballot() public {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: SyntaxError: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:26:5: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    function Ballot() public {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Ballot {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Migrations {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:57:46: TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
    function getCount() public view returns (uint[8]) {
                                             ^-----^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v8.12.0
 please help how to solve this ?
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use `constructor()` to define constructor.

**Replace**

```
function Ballot() public
```

with

```
constructor() public
```

2. Pass index of array whose value you want in return. Do the iteration on application side and not in smart contract.

**Replace**

```
function getCount() public view returns (uint[8]) {
        return proposals;
    }
```

with

```
function getCount(uint index) public view returns (uint) {
        return proposals[index];
    }
```

Comment: bc@bc-HP-Pro-3090-Microtower-PC:~/bheem/Ballot2$ truffle compile
Error parsing /home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol: ParsedContract.sol:61:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
}
^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v8.12.0

Comment: As **proposals** variable is declared as _public_ . So **getCount** method is not required, you directly call the method `proposals(index)`.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you have just warnings, but the first error is: `/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:26:5: SyntaxError: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.` This is the important part and you have to fix this.

Solidity version 0.4.22 introduced new keyword `constructor` which should be used for constructors. Since version 0.5.0, the use of keyword `constructor` for a constructor was mandatory - you can no longer use a constructor function which has the same name as the contract name.

So just rename your constructor function from `function Ballot() public {` to `constructor() public {`.

Furthermore, you have another error: `,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Ballot.sol:57:46: TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.`

Fix this by adding a `memory` keyword. Also your returned variable's signature does not match the return signature. You are giving `uint[4] memory` as parameter and returning it, but the function expects a `uint[8] memory` as return value. So the function should probably be:

```
function getCount() public view returns (uint[4] memory) {
    return proposals;
}
```

Comment: i have changed my code but still getting error help me ?

Comment: ,/home/bc/bheem/Ballot2/contracts/Migrations.sol:20:5: TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    ^--------^
Compilation failed. See above.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function Migrations() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}